# Import Tradingview data to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, stockquotes

I've tried to import RSI from trading view to google sheet but I can't.
The formula I used :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/technicals/","//div[@id='technicals-root']/td[@class='cell-2-juHm8n']")
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

by disabling JavaScript there is nothing left to be scrapped:

[image]